# Xcode project (zip downloaded from github) builds, but I get a black screen in the simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git, github

I downloaded the .zip of one of my repositories on github and it builds perfectly. However, the simulator shows a black screen upon loading. I checked the repo for missing files, but have so far found no irregularities. The info.plist file is the same as my local copy, as are the main.storyboard and launchscreen.storyboard files.
I think I'm still missing something here. How can I fix this?

Comment: reset the sim and try again?

Comment: Doesn't work, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Go to your first screen in storyboard and set **Is Initial View Controller** to true in its `Attributes inspector`

Comment: sorry but the issue still persists. The initial view controller had already been set.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your Launch Screen File and Main Interface in Target's General tab. It'd be set to LaunchScreen.storyboard and Main.storyboard (In general)